# Getting System Error Code 1060 (service does not exist) after using function OpenServiceA

Tags: windows, powershell, winapi, scripting, windows-services

I would like to control a Service (e.g. WinRM) using Powershell via the WinAPI. (Just for an exercise).
After running the script, I get a handle to the service control manager database. However, I dont get a handle of the "WinRM"-Service. I only get the Error-Code 1060 (The specified service does not exist as an installed service.) after executing the OpenServiceA-Function.

**Service.ps1**

```
$loadAdvapi32 = @"

  public struct LPSERVICE_STATUS {
      public uint dwServiceType;
      public uint dwCurrentState;
      public uint dwControlsAccepted;
      public uint dwWin32ExitCode;
      public uint dwServiceSpecificExitCode;
      public uint dwCheckPoint;
      public uint dwWaitHint;
  }

 [DllImport("Advapi32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
 public static extern 
 IntPtr OpenSCManager(string  lpMachineName,
                      string  lpDatabaseName,
                      uint    dwDesiredAccess);

 [DllImport("Advapi32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
 public static extern 
 IntPtr OpenServiceA(IntPtr    hSCManager,
                     string    lpServiceName,
                     uint      dwDesiredAccess);

 [DllImport("Advapi32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
 public static extern 
 bool ControlService(IntPtr           hService,
                     uint             dwControl,
                     out LPSERVICE_STATUS lpServiceStatus);
"@

$loadKernel32 = @"
 [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
 public static extern 
 int GetLastError();
"@

Add-Type -MemberDefinition $loadAdvapi32 -Name 'Advapi32' -Namespace 'Win32';
Add-Type -MemberDefinition $loadKernel32 -Name 'Kernel32' -Namespace 'Win32';

$lpMachineName = [NullString]::Value;
$lpDatabaseName = [NullString]::Value;

# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-security-and-access-rights
$SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS = 0xF003F;
$SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS = 0xF01FF;


$hSCManager = [Win32.Advapi32]::OpenSCManager($lpMachineName, $lpDatabaseName, $SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
[Win32.Kernel32]::GetLastError()

$schService = [Win32.Advapi32]::OpenServiceA($hSCManager, "WinRM", $SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);
[Win32.Kernel32]::GetLastError()
```

**Output**

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> C:\Service.ps1
0
1060
```

I already tried/checked:

1. WinRM-Service exists and is installed
2. Running the script in an elevated Powershell
3. Checked if the Name of the Service is correct

Comment: Make sure you start Powershell by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.  The service should be accessible if you see it in Task Manager.  Error indicates either you are not running as admin or the task is not shown in Task Manager.

Comment: I already did run it with "Run Ad Admin". Additionally, the Service does exist if I use "Get-Service WinRM".

Comment: Use Ansi instead of Auto.  The method is OpenService (not OpenSevviceA which only works if you rename the entry point).  See : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/OpenService.html

Comment: There is no `OpenService()` entry point. There is `OpenServiceA()` (Ansi) and `OpenServiceW()` (Unicode). Using `CharSet.Auto` automatically picks between them if you omit the `A`/`W` suffix in the declaration, like how the `OpenSCManager()` declaration does (which is really picking between `OpenSCManagerA()` and `OpenSCManagerW()`).  If you use `OpenServiceA()` directly, you need to use `CharSet.Ansi`.  Better to use `OpenService()` and `CharSet.Auto`, though